# Create a google maps link from API Map with multiple waypoint

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have built a web app that uses the google maps v3 API to build a map with directions multiple waypoints.

```
 jQuery.getJSON(driverURL, function(dData){
       var routeObject = {};
       var lat = dData.Location.lat;
       var lng = dData.Location.lng;
       routeObject.origin = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
       routeObject.destination = new google.maps.LatLng(endRoute.lat, endRoute.lng);
       routeObject.waypoints = waypoints;
       routeObject.travelMode = google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING;
       routeObject.optimizeWaypoints = true;
       directionsService.route(routeObject, function(response, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                 var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
                       polylineOptions: {
                            strokeColor: colors[driverLines.length]
                       }
                 });
                 directionsDisplay.setMap(dMap);
                 directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            } else {
                 window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
            }
       });
  });
```

I have the Map, the waypoints, the start and the end all stored, but I'd like to be able to generate a google maps clickable link to the directions for this route that I can send to users. I can find how to send a link with a single marker, but not how to generate a map link with the full route direction.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#directions_mode

Comment: That's exactly what the code above does. It takes waypoints and creates a directs display and draws the directions on the map. But those docs DO NOT answer the question I asked which is: How to create a clickable link to a google map with those waypoints and route on it. As in a maps.google.com link that can be sent to a user with all the waypoints, and directions.

Comment: The only documented way to create a "google map" with directions on it is via the embed API.

Comment: Not to be combative, but you're not understanding the question. I am using the google maps v3 API to create the map on my site. The map on my site has all the waypoints and the route on it. That isn't the question. The question is: Is it possible to create a link that would allow a user to get the same map, with waypoints, on maps.google.com.

Comment: The only documented way I know to do that is to use the embed API.  There are posts with details about how to do that with the "old" google maps interface, those will probably work for now, but they aren't documented, so may stop working at some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out, and it's actually easier than I thought, but took some doing.

First I took some of the waypoints I had, as addresses, not lat/lng points, and built a route map on maps.google.com. Then I looked at how the URL for that map was constructed. Very simple to re-create.

The URL is just http://maps.google.com/dir/starting address as address,city,state,zip/waypoint as address,city,state,zip/waypoint/ending address as address,city,state,zip And you're done. If you're using lat/lng coordinates for your start,waypoint,end locations you'll have to first geo-code them using the V3 api then extract the address information from the returned result and insert those in your URL, but it works.

Here's how I made the final link that has a start, a bunch of waypoints, and an ending location. I start with a JSON object, called Data, that has all the address info in it and build a long string from it, in the format Google Maps expects:

```
var dirs = ''
for(var x = 0; x<Data.length;x++){
    dirs += Data[x].Address + "," + Data[x].City + "," + Data[x].State + "," + Data[x].Zip + "/";
}
```

Then, I add the start and end locations to it:

```
var dirLink = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/dir/';
dirLink += start.Address + "," + start.City + "," + start.State + "," + start.Zip + "/" + dirs + end.Address + "," + end.City + "," + end.State + "," + end.Zip;
```

And dirLink will be a complete link that will give directions from start.Address through all the waypoints to end.Address.

Answer (score 1):

Don`t forget for 
In script :

```
function initMap() {
    var pointA = new google.maps.LatLng(51.7519, -1.2578),
        pointB = new google.maps.LatLng(51.509865, -0.118092),
        pointC = new google.maps.LatLng(50.8429, -0.1313),
        myOptions = {
            zoom: 7,
            center: pointA
        },
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), myOptions),
        // Instantiate a directions service.
        directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService,
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
            map: map
        }),
        markerA = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: pointA,
            title: "point A",
            label: "A",
            map: map
        }),
        markerB = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: pointB,
            title: "point B",
            label: "B",
            map: map
        }),
        markerC = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: pointC,
            title: "point C",
            label: "C",
            map: map
        });

    // get route from A to B
    calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, pointA, pointB, pointC);

}


function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, pointA, pointB, pointC) {
    var first = new google.maps.LatLng(51.509865, -0.118092); //we can get them from params.
    var request = {
        origin: pointA,
        destination: pointC,
        waypoints: [{location: first, stopover: false}
          ], //here array of waypoints
        optimizeWaypoints: true,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            var route = response.routes[0];
            var summaryPanel = document.getElementById("directions_panel");
            summaryPanel.innerHTML = "";
            // For each route, display summary information.
            for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
                var routeSegment = i + 1;
                summaryPanel.innerHTML += "<b>Route Segment: " + routeSegment + "</b><br />";
                summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].start_address + " to ";
                summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].end_address + "<br />";
                summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].distance.text + "<br /><br />";
            }
        } else {
            alert("directions response " + status);
        }
    });     
}
initMap();
```